# Conditions to be imposed on a bounded set

Tags: complex-analysis

let $K\subseteq \mathbb C$ be a  bounded set.Let $f,g$ be two entire functions such that $f|_K=g|_K$.

What conditions should  be imposed out of

compact,connected,uncountable,finite

on $K$ to conclude $f=g$ over whole of $\mathbb C$?

I know that if $f,g $ are holomorphic in $\Gamma$ and $g=f$ on an open set in $\Gamma$ then $f=g$ on whole of $\Gamma$.

How to solve this?

Comment: If two holomorphic functions coincide on a set which is not discrete, then they coincide everywhere. This is a corollary of the open mapping theorem.

Comment: what is meant by discrete?

Comment: A set is discrite when it has no limit points (a limit point is a point such that every neighbourhood has infinite intersection with the set).